# I need to find fast chop with similar functionality to slowChop

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have implemented BinarySearchTree.slowChop, but need to implement faster algorithm.

Definition:

```
public BinarySearchTree<Node,T> chop(T x)
```

that chops our sorted set into two parts at element x. The SSet this contains elements < x, and the returned SSet is a SSet that contains elements >= x. This should work for all elements regardless of whether they are in this.

For example, suppose s={2,4,6,8}. Then s.chop(3) returns {4,6,8} and s becomes {2}. We would get the same result for s.chop(4).

`slowChop` method is implemented but take O(n) time, need to reduce it to at least O(h) if tree is balanced.

```
public BinarySearchTree<Node,T> slowChop(T x) {
        Node sample = super.newNode();
        BinarySearchTree<Node,T> other = new 
        BinarySearchTree<Node, T>(sample);

    // Iterate through the n nodes in-order.
    // When see value >=x, add to new BST in O(height) time, and
    // remove it from this BST (on next iteration) in O(height) time.
        Iterator<T> it = iterator();
    T prev = null;
    while( it.hasNext() ) {
      T curr = (T)(it.next());
      if( c.compare(curr, x) >= 0 ) { // we have our first >= x 
        other.add(curr);
        if( prev != null ) {
          this.remove(prev);          // safe to remove now
        }
        prev = curr;
      }
    }
    if( prev != null ) {
      this.remove(prev); // edge case, get that last one!
    }
    return other; 
  }
```

Following drive link contains the helper classes: BinarySearchTree BinaryTree DefaultComparator SSet

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Uc6pNFg8e3WyeiinVFk6yA4W0LdB6UGx?usp=sharing

Comment: Surely if it is balanced you can just take the things to the left and move your split point to the top and re-balance (something like that ... I can still see the transparency paper slide from CS101 like it was yesterday ....)

Comment: It sounds like if you're dealing with a binary search tree the problem is as simple as searching for the smallest node with value >= target. If that smallest node is equal to the target, put the right subtree of the smallest node into the result and remove the subtree with the root equal to the found node from the original. I'll leave it up to you to deal with the case where the smallest node with value >= target has value > target. The time complexity of the algorithm is logarithmic on the total number of nodes, and if the tree is balanced is linear on height.

Comment: Have a look at the code for[ java.util.TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) - it does the algorithm you are doing.